# Install libraries in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, ta-lib

I want to know how to install the talib library in Spyder.

I installed Spyder directly (not anaconda). I get this error: No module named 'talib', can it be installed directly in spyder or do I have to do it from the terminal? I don't know how to do this last thing...